# Programmatically Selecting Theme Based on URL

Tags: plugin-development, themes, mobile

I've inherited a site which has a mobile version. Let's call it qqq.com. It has a Varnish server in front of it to cache the pages. But it seems the Varnish server is also detecting mobile requests, and changing the URL to m.qqq.com.

The WP install is then switching to the qqq-mobile theme, instead of the qqq theme.

How would you do that? I'm trying to locate the code that does this, so I can do the same thing on my local dev instance.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The activated theme is stored in the `options` table: `template` is the parent theme, `stylesheet` is the child theme. If there is no child theme the two values will be the same.

The current hostname (URL without protocol or path) is available in the `$_SERVER` variable.

You can then hook into the `stylesheet` and `template` filters to force a different theme.

```
function use_mobile_theme( $current_theme ) {
    // If the domain is m.qqq.com and the current theme is 'qqq'
    if ( 'm.qqq.com' === $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] && 'qqq' === $current_theme ) {
        // Use the 'qqq-mobile' theme instead
        return 'qqq-mobile';
    } else {
        // Otherwise, keep the current theme
        return $current_theme;
    }
}

add_filter( 'stylesheet', 'use_mobile_theme' );
add_filter( 'template', 'use_mobile_theme' );
```

If `qqq-mobile` **is a child theme**, remove the `add_filter( 'template', ...` line.