# Child theme in separate Wordpress Install

Tags: theme-development, templates, child-theme

I am looking to create a mobile-only child theme for my site on a separate WordPress install but which is on the same server at the main install.

Example of folder Structure:

> **mysite**
>
> > wp-content
> >
> > > Themes
> > >
> > > > parent-theme
> >
> > **tablet**
> >
> > > wp-content
> > >
> > > > themes
> > > >
> > > > > child-theme

Would I have to duplicate the parent theme into the Tablet theme directory and repeat every time the parent theme is changed or is there a solution in which the child-theme can use the parent theme from the main install directory?

**Note:** WP Multisite is not an option due to all sites sharing the same database.

Comment: How are you going to find out if an incoming page request is from a mobile client?

Comment: Using WURLF, user agent detection. We already use this method in our current set up using individual themes for each install

Comment: Yes, but are you detecting the device on the server level and then redirect to the appropriate WP-install, or are you detecting it in the WP-install and want to switch the theme there, if necessary?

Comment: It is detected on the server level and user is directed to wp-install, we have a different WP for Desktop, Mobile, Tablet

Comment: In that case, I wouldn't know. Handing over to a different theme in the same installation might be easier. See this, for a slightly different problem: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/128504/programmatically-selecting-theme-based-on-url

Comment: Thanks but I am unable to change the current set up due to management :)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently what you want has been [discussed for seven years](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/13239) now and still is waiting for a final solution.

However, since 4.7 there is the function [`get_parent_theme_file_path`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_parent_theme_file_path/), which is called when a parent theme file is needed. This function has a filter which allows you to change the location. So, if you insert that filter into your child theme, you should be able to redirect all requests for a parent theme file to another WP installation altogether (if the security settings on the parent install allow outside calls to individual theme files).

I haven't actually tried this, but it should work.

Comment: This would have to be used for nearly every file though, would not a true 'child theme' imo.

Comment: Yes, if you don't want your parent theme duplicated in the child install, every call to a parent theme file must be redirected like this. (personally I would just duplicate the parent theme to avoid complications)